# Android ApplicationInfo is a game?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-applicationinfo

I am a beginner to Andriod dev.
I am trying to get a list of all games installed in my phone.
Is there a way to know the App is 'a game' from either AppInfo or PackageInfo?

Either send the appinfo to google market place and retrieve the related info would help?

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to fetch HTML from app's Play Store site, e.g. 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gameloft.android.ANMP.GloftA7HM where `com.gameloft.android.ANMP.GloftA7HM` is replaced with proper package name retrieved from PackageInfo
and search for some keyword which will be unique for games, e.g.  `/store/apps/category/GAME`

This solution is not very good as it could be broken when Google changes layout of Play Store website but there is no app category information available directly in Android APIs.